# Multi-Node Hadoop in kubernetes

Tags: hadoop, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I already intalled minikube the single node Kubernetes cluster, I just want a help of how to deploy a multi-node hadoop cluster inside this kubernetes node, I need a starting point please!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For clarification, do you want hadoop to leverage k8s components to run jobs or do you just want it to run as a k8s pod?

Unfortunately I could not find an example of hadoop built as a Kubernetes scheduler. You can probably still run it similar to the [spark example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/spark).

Update: Spark now ships with better integration for Kubernetes. Information can be found here [here](https://apache-spark-on-k8s.github.io/userdocs/running-on-kubernetes.html)

Comment: Yes I want to leverage k8s components to run jobs.

Comment: thanks Cmluciano for the great spark example.I have a question: where did the link between the workers and master exactly happen? in the code or Implicitly? and how?

Comment: @K.Ali I'm not 100% sure how that happens. I will update my answer with the official Spark docs.